# A noun which describes how well understood something is

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

I have a list of components and I'm putting a paragraph together which describes that these components have a wide range of values for various properties.  So far I've got:

> Currently we have a series of reporting solutions, from various eras, written in various languages, deployed throughout the organisation.  These reporting solutions have various levels of documentation, adaptability and [how-well-people-understand-them].

I need a word for the [how-well-people-understand-them] and I'm drawing a blank!

Comment: I've considered things like 'comprehension'; this (and other words of its ilk) seem to me to suggest that the object comprehends something else, not other people comprehending the object.

Comment: Don't you actually mean something like: the degree to which these reports give [useful and comprehensible] insights on what they're about? e.g. suitability, utility, fitness, etc. maybe even convenience, effectiveness or potency?

Comment: @Denis No.  I mean whether people in the organisation know what the components are, how they are used and what they can do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

perhaps *familiarity* per google:

> (noun)
>   close acquaintance with or knowledge of something.
>   "increase customer familiarity with a product"
>   synonyms:   acquaintance with, awareness of, experience with/of, insight into, knowledge of, understanding of, comprehension of, grasp of, skill in, ...

This seems to capture what it means for people in the company to know about the procedures to varying degrees.

Comment: I think this is a good fit for what I'm after.  Thank you!

Comment: I think "familiarity" implies the reports are familiar (with something), rather than other people being familiar with the reports.

Answer (score 1):

What about **clarity**?

> Currently we have a series of reporting solutions, from various eras, written in various languages, deployed throughout the organisation. These reporting solutions have various levels of documentation, adaptability and **clarity**.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, scratch this; in typing my comment, it's come to me:
Comprehensibility.

Comment: If this is for a marketing document, though, that word would implicitly convey that the reports aren't always comprehensible.

Answer (score 0):

**Plain** can be a good word for your sentence.

Plain: not difficult; simple or easy